# Mongo index for query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with millions of records. I am trying to implement an autocomplete on a field called term that I broke down into an array of words called words. My query is very slow because I am missing something with regards to the index. Can someone please help?

I have the following query:

```
db.vx.find({ 
    semantic: "product", 
    concept: true, 
    active: true, 
    $and: [ { words: { $regex: "^doxycycl.*" } } ] 
}).sort({ length: 1 }).limit(100).explain()
```

The explain output says that no index was used even though I have the following index:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "words" : 1,
        "active" : 1,
        "concept" : 1,
        "semantic" : 1
    },
    "name" : "words_1_active_1_concept_1_semantic_1",
    "ns" : "mydatabase.vx"
}
```

Comment: - I don't get how your field is callled `term` if you say and query for a field called `words`.

Comment: Words is an array that contains each word in the filed term as term is a sentence

Comment: So there is no `term` field. Your document have an array of string `words` and that's all, am I right?

Comment: There is a term field but I don't query against it because if the search is multiple words from the term field but in the wrong order I can no longer search against it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this; when I set up a collection with these fields and this index, and run this query, it says that there was a "FETCH" stage followed by an "IXSCAN" stage. There must be something different in our setups, I suppose. Could you show in more detail what your data looks like, and what the explain() returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the compound index is exploited correctly using the mongo shell 
`db.vx.find({YOURQUERY}).explain('executionStats')`

and check the field `winningPlan.stage`:

- `COLLSCAN` means the indexes are partially used or not used at all.
- `IXSCAN` means the indexes are used correctly in this query.

You can also check if the [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/) fits your needs since is way more fast than $regex operator. 
https://comsysto.com/blog-post/mongodb-full-text-search-vs-regular-expressions